# Powershell $? Symbol

Tags: powershell-3.0

What does the PowerShell $? symbol mean and what is it used for?

I'm currently using it in the context of the following code block:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { param($proc, $arg) Start-Process $proc -ArgumentList $arg -Wait } -ArgumentList $processName, $processArgs

if ($? -ne $true)
{
}
```

So I'm assuming it is pulling a Boolean value if the Invoke-Command successfully executed, but am not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see about_automatic_variables :

```
get-help about_Automatic_Variables
```

> $?
>   Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>   TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.